# How to set run-time character set in C?

Tags: c, linux, character-encoding

How to set run-time character set in the C programming language, in linux environment?

For example, I want to set it to iso8859-1, utf-8, or ascii.

Comment: Do you mean, the system locale?

Comment: @ruakh I am not sure, I just read from the book that depending on different run-time character sets, the output of sth like `printf( "%c", '\xa3')` would be different.

Comment: I believe you should avoid *setting* that inside your program (unless it is some server program perhaps); leave the user the freedom to set it globally.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I may know what do you mean, I am just reading a book about C tell me about run-time character set, and want to do an experiment.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be a little more specific about what you mean. For the most part, C doesn't really have a character set; its strings are simply null-delimited strings of bytes, and doesn't do anything to encode or decode them.

There are a few functions in the C standard library, and in POSIX which depend on the current locale. You can use use [`setlocale`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/setlocale.html) to set the current locale; it defaults to the C locale, in which strings are treated as ASCII and compared according to byte values.

If you want to convert character sets, use [`iconv`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/iconv.html); this will allow you to convert buffers from one encoding to another. For instance, if you represent your text internally in UTF-8, but want to print it out in ISO-8859-1, this is what you would use.

**edit to add**: From a comment on another answer, you ask:

> I set my terminal's expected character set to be "ISO 8859-1", but why when I call the function `setlocale( LC_CTYPE, NULL );`, it still returns `C`? I think it should return `ISO 8859-1` as this is the terminal's expected charset.

When the program starts up, its locale is always "C". If you want to set the locale based on the environment variables, you need to call `setlocale( LC_ALL, "")` or `setlocal( LC_CTYPE, "")`; that is, you need to pass in an empty string, and then the locale will be set based on your environment variables.

Answer (score 3):

What `printf( "%c", '\xa3')` does is always the same -- it outputs *one byte* with the value 0xA3 (= 163) to the standard output stream.

What is then shown on your screen depends on how your terminal (e.g., xterm or the Linux console) reacts to seeing a byte with value 163 written to it. That is a question of the character setting *of your terminal*, and there is no direct way your C program can influence it. What you need to do is allow the C program to *find out* what charset the terminal expects, and then generate output that matches that.

Simple programs can often can get away with assuming that the charset their input is in is also the charset their output is expected to be in, and then they just ignore charset issues and simply reproduce high-bit bytes in their output exactly as they appeared in the input. (The UTF-8 encoding of Unicode is deliberately designed to make this strategy work in many cases).

However, when that is not the case -- such as if your program contains hardcoded string with non-English letters -- you need to use the locale functions to figure out which character encoding your program is supposed to produce, and then make sure to do that. Libraries such as libiconv can often help with this relatively painlessly.

Comment: I set my terminal's expected character set to be "ISO 8859-1", but why when I call the function `setlocale( LC_CTYPE, NULL );`, it still returns `C`? I think it should return `ISO 8859-1` as this is the terminal's expected charset.

Comment: @UniMouS: `setlocale` is not psychic -- it doesn't know what the terminal is actually doing, only what you have set the environment variables to _claim_ the terminal is doing. If the environment stays silent about what charset the process should use, there is no way to detect what the terminal is actually doing.

Comment: But when I type `echo $LC_CTYPE` in my terminal, the output is: `ISO88591`.

Comment: @UniMouS: Do you have a locale of that name installed? It's a somewhat unusual name; usually the name of the charset would be `ISO-8859-1` rather than `ISO88591`. And if I remember correctly (it's been a while), the value of the locale environment variables such as `LC_CTYPE` is supposed to refer to a complete locale definition (even if only part of it is used), not just the name of a charset.

Answer (score 1):

See `setlocale(3)`, which sets the program's current locale.

Answer (score 1):

Standard C provides the `setlocale()` function to set a locale. The value for LC_CTYPE defines the character type. For some finer details, also see what [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html) has to say.
To find out the locales supported on your system, run

```
locale -a
```

Comment: What can I do, if I cannot find the character set I want to use in the `locale -a` list?

Comment: You should in that case install other locales on your system.

Comment: Beware that installing a locale _description_ is not by itself going to make terminal windows and other programs that display text on the screen know how to deal with the character encoding. Fonts for that need to be installed separately, and terminal programs must be told to use them when they start.

Comment: @UniMouS What character set are you looking for? UTF-8 is able to deal with just about anything you can think of. It's even termed *the last character set you will ever need.*

Comment: @Jens I know that UTF-8 is enough, but I just want to use iso 8859-1 to do some experiment about compatibility. So, I need to use it.